# Has been + PP vs Was + PP

Tags: passive-voice

I'm confused with below sentence,

1)She mentioned that it **has been** named as the Indian Wars.

2)She mentioned that it **was** named as the Indian Wars.

First one is incorrect?

Comment: If the first one would be `it had been`, both will correct.

Comment: @ElgsQianChen       How about  ' Native citizens were died during the war' or 'Native citizens died during the war'  Why first one is wrong?

Comment: `were killed`, `were dead` or `died` all sound right. `were died` is wrong. Someone dies, but they are not died by anything.

Comment: You don't want to include "as", by the way. "She mentioned that it was named 'The Indian Wars'", for example.

Answer (score 3):

A passive verb needs to have [to be] before the main verb (which should be in past participle form).  'has been' and 'was' are both forms of [to be], thus both sentences are grammatically correct.

The difference is the tense:

- 'has been named' is [present perfect](https://youtu.be/RvzWOYXz-MY).  It implies that it was named the Indian Wars in the past and that the name still holds in the present.
- 'was named' is past simple.  It only refers to a past time, possibly the first time the Indian Wars were named as such.

Both might be appropriate for your context; it just depends on what implications you want to include.  To decide which is better, you'll have to look into [the differences between the tenses](https://youtu.be/RvzWOYXz-MY).

But as far as [Passive Voice](https://youtu.be/_PCCZ9Pvk2s) is concerned, both sentences are valid.